# How to print multiple values from BeautifulSoup with Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape two values from a webpage using BeautifulSoup. When printing only one value, the content looks good. However, when printing two values (to the same line), html-code is displayed around the one of the values..

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as urllib2


list_open = open("source.txt")
read_list = list_open.read()
line_in_list = read_list.split("\n")


i = 0
for url in line_in_list:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read(), 'html.parser')
    sku = soup.find_all(attrs={'class': "identifier"})
    description = soup.find_all(attrs={'class': "description"})
    for text in description:
        print((sku), text.getText())
    i += 1
```

And the output looks like this:

```
[<span class="identifier">112404</span>] A natural for...etc
[<span class="identifier">110027</span>] After what...etc
[<span class="identifier">03BA5730</span>] Argentina is know...etc
[<span class="identifier">090030</span>] To be carried...etc
```

The output should preferably be without the `[<span class="identifier">`-thing around the numbers...

I guess the problem is in the last for-loop, but I have no idea how to correct it. All help is appreciated. Thanks! -Espen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to `zip()` identifiers and descriptions and call `getText()` for every tag found in the loop:

```
identifiers = soup.find_all(attrs={'class': "identifier"})
descriptions = soup.find_all(attrs={'class': "description"})

for identifier, description in zip(identifiers, descriptions):
    print(identifier.getText(), description.getText())
```

Answer (score 1):

`find_all()` returns a `ResultSet`, which is more or less a fancy list. Printing a `ResultSet` will include the surrounding left and right square brackets that typically denote a list, and the items (tags) will be displayed within.

Your sample output suggests that the HTML for each URL contains one SKU and one description per URL. If that is correct then your code could just pick off the first item in each `ResultSet` like this:

```
sku = soup.find_all(attrs={'class': "identifier"})
description = soup.find_all(attrs={'class': "description"})
print(sku[0].get_text(), description[0].get_text())
```

Or, you could just find the first of each using `find()`:

```
sku = soup.find(attrs={'class': "identifier"})
description = soup.find(attrs={'class': "description"})
print(sku.get_text(), description.get_text())
```

However, your *code* suggests that there can be multiple descriptions for each SKU because you are iterating over the description result set. Perhaps there can be multiple SKUs and descriptions per page (in which case see [@alecxe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35399716/21945))? It's difficult to tell.

If you could update your question by adding live URLs or sample HTML we could offer better advice.

Comment: Thank you @mhawke. There is only one description for each sku, both solutions worked in my case.